# SQL WHERE condition that one field's string can be found in another field

Tags: t-sql, substring, charindex

Here's some sample data

```
    ID | sys1lname | sys2lname
------------------------------------
    1  | JOHNSON   | JOHNSON
    2  | FULTON    | ANDERS-FULTON
    3  | SMITH     | SMITH-DAVIDS
    4  | HARRISON  | JONES
```

The goal is to find records where the last names do NOT match, BUT allow when sys1lname can be found somewhere within sys2lname, which may or may not be a hyphenated name. So from the above data, only record 4 should return.

When I put this `(SUBSTRING(sys2lname, CHARINDEX(sys2lname, ccm.NAME_LAST), LEN(sys1lname)))` in the `SELECT` statement it will properly return the part of sys2lname that matches sys1lname.

But when I use that in the `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE 1=1
    AND sys1lname <> sys2lname
    OR sys1lname not in ('%' + (SUBSTRING(sys2lname, CHARINDEX(sys1lname, sys2lname), LEN(sys1lname))))
```

the records with hyphenated names are in the result set.

And I can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a `NOT LIKE`:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE sys2lname NOT LIKE '%' + sys1lname + '%';
```

If you could have a name like `'Smith'` in `sys1lname` and `'BlackSmith'` (or even `'Green-Blacksmith'`) in `sys2lname` and don't want them to match, I would use `STRING_SPLIT` and a `NOT EXISTS`:

```sql
SELECT ID
FROM dbo.YourTable YT
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM STRING_SPLIT(YT.sys2lname,'-') SS
                  WHERE SS.[value] = YT.sys1lname);
```